# Finding a valueMember in a combobox dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-statements

I am trying to find a particular valueMember in a combobox for a for loop. This is what I have so far

```
for (int i = 0; i <= this.cmbAssignedTo.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (this.cmbAssignedTo.Items.Contains(clsColOpsUtilities.GetUserID()))
                {
                    this.cmbAssignedTo.SelectedValue = clsColOpsUtilities.GetUserID();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.cmbAssignedTo.Text = "All";
                }
            }
```

cmbAssignedTo is the combobox. How would I find the valuemember of each item in the combobox and see if the value I am seeking is in it?
Thanks

P.S.
this is the code for getUSerID:

' public static string GetUserID()
        {
            try
            {
                return Environment.UserName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the value got from `clsColOpsUtilities.GetUserID()` may match some `SelectedValue` of some item of your `ComboBox`, try this code:

```
cmbAssignedTo.SelectedValue = clsColOpsUtilities.GetUserID();
//If the GetUserID() doesn't match any ValueMember, then the SelectedIndex will be -1
if(cmbAssignedTo.SelectedIndex == -1) cmbAssignedTo.Text = "All";
```

**NOTE**: I would add some `Item` with `Text = "All"` for the combobox, so that it can be selected.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you're iterating over each item and then checking the box (each time) to see if the entire list of items in the box contains the user id.

This does the same thing:

```
var userId = clsColOpsUtilities.GetUserID();

this.cmbAssignedTo.SelectedValue = this.cmbAssignedTo.Items.Contains(userId) ? userId : "All";
```

If your combo box's items contains the userId, then set the value of the combobox to userId, otherwise, set it to "All".

Without any more info about what your code is doing and what you expect it to do, it's hard to know exactly what you want in an answer.

Comment: I want to check for a userid in a filter for a table on the front end. if the user is in the dropdown (by their login id) then the table filters to their record. If not the dropdown defaults to "All" which would then show the whole table

Comment: Does GetUserID return a string ID, or is it returning the same object that you're adding to cmbAssignedTo? Can you post that object?

Comment: GetUserID returns a string of the userid of who is logged into the computer. cmbAssignTo is populated with a list of userids as values and display the username associated with the id's

Comment: I will use this when I revisit the solution one more time. Thanks